# /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4はあるのにsymbol lookup errorが出る

Tags: qt

```
klusters: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZN16QIODevicePrivate4peekEPcx

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May 12 16:03 /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4 -> libQtNetwork.so.4.8.6

ldd /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc429bd000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00002b0200180000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b0200690000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b02008ad000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b0200ac3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b0200dca000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b020104e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b0201264000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b02015f9000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00002b02017fd000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002b0201a01000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00002b0201c0a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003a2ee00000)
```

原因がお分かりの方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか

Comment: `ldd klusters`でライブラリの依存関係を確認すると、`libQtCore.so`は同じファイルを指しますか? (`_ZN16QIODevicePrivate4peekEPcx`はlibQtCore`に実体があるはずなので)

Comment: ldd /usr/bin/klusters|grep libQtCore
 libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4 (0x0000003a37200000)

Answer (score 1):

先のコメントで確認してもらったとおり、`klusters`が参照している`libQtCore.so.4`が`/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4`となっており、`/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/libQtCore.so.4`とならないのが原因と考えられます。
(`/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4`には`_ZN16QIODevicePrivate4peekEPcx`は含まれていないと予想される)

ビルド時(リンク時)のライブラリ検索パスと実行時のライブラリ検索パスが異なっていると予想します。対策としては、

1. 環境変数`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`に`/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib`を設定して`klusters`を実行する。
2. `/etc/ld.so.conf`を編集して`/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib`を`/usr/lib64`より優先にする。

という方法があると思います。

Comment: 予想は大正解でした。対策は複数のアカウント対象でしたので、ld.co.confでなければだったんですが、何度やっても/usr/lib64を読み込んでしまうので/etc/profileに環境変数を設定しました。すごく助かりましたし、私の勉強にもなりました。ありがとうございました。